How to align the text to left side when row-reverse is applied
I'm making a chat bot using Python and Streamlit. I want the chat to show User messages on the right side and Bot messages on the left side. I'm using CSS with row-reversed for this, but the text size and chat message size aren't changing as I want.
Here's the CSS I tried:
For User messages:
div.stChatMessage.st-emotion-cache-1c7y2kd.eeusbqq4
{ 
    width: 350px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-end;
 
}

For Bot messages (highlighted in black)
div.stChatMessage.st-emotion-cache-4oy321.eeusbqq4
{
    background-color: hsla(208, 29%, 78%, 0.66);
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    width: 550px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    
}

For reporducing the code, I am using the code from the link below:
https://docs.streamlit.io/develop/tutorials/llms/build-conversational-apps
(refer Build a ChatGPT-like app section)
from openai import OpenAI
import streamlit as st


st.title("ChatGPT-like clone")

client = OpenAI(api_key=st.secrets["OPENAI_API_KEY"])


with open ('design.css') as source:
    st.markdown(f"<style>{source.read()}</style>",unsafe_allow_html=True)

if "openai_model" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["openai_model"] = "gpt-3.5-turbo"

if "messages" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.messages = []

for message in st.session_state.messages:
    with st.chat_message(message["role"]):
        st.markdown(message["content"])

if prompt := st.chat_input("What is up?"):
    st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})
    with st.chat_message("user"):
        st.markdown(prompt)

    with st.chat_message("assistant"):
        stream = client.chat.completions.create(
            model=st.session_state["openai_model"],
            messages=[
                {"role": m["role"], "content": m["content"]}
                for m in st.session_state.messages
            ],
            stream=True,
        )
        response = st.write_stream(stream)
    st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response})

The output I am getting

The Output expected should be somewhat similar to the below image. Left side Bot messages and on right side the user messages.


but the HTML is absolutely required since it is the part that will be displayed according to your requirements - if anything, the code you posted (except the CSS) is not relevant since it does not pertain to the UI/display issue you need help with :)

The issue you are having is from using both flex-direction: row-reverse and justify-content: flex-end, which contradict each other for the desired result. Try using either one of the declarations.
Alternatively, I think this example is closer to what you are wanting:


div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

div.user { 
  align-self: flex-end;
  padding: .5em;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

div.bot {
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding: .5em;
  background-color: hsla(208, 29%, 78%, 0.66);
  border-radius: 25px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="user">book hotel</div>
  <div class="bot">Where?</div>
  <div class="user">Madison, WI</div>
  <div class="bot">When?</div>
</div>



